# Cannot connect to a connection in C# with sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this code

```
public static string connString = @"CARLOPCASTILLO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectFinalDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

My program was working since I modified it in a school computer, then I transferred it back again in my pc.. And I got this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
>
> {"Keyword not supported: 'carlopcastillo\sqlexpress;initial
> catalog'."}

Comment: I swear I changed it back again to my pc's sql server

Comment: A quick look in examples shows connection strings starting with `Data Source=`.

Comment: have you tried copying the string in notepad ++ then back in the .cs file, I had a similar problem where Windows was adding hidden characters and weird encoding in the string.

Answer (score 4):

you missed `Data Source` keyword:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=CARLOPCASTILLO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectFinalDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, maybe I should stop relying more on stackoverflow and start solving my own codes

Answer (score 2):

Change your **connection** string to:

```
"Data Source=CARLOPCASTILLO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectFinalDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Generate connection string using Visual Studio

[how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/)

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in Web.Config, into connectionStrings:

```
<add name="" connectionString="Data Source=CARLOPCASTILLO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectFinalDatabase;Integrated Security=True"/>
```